# XSS protection with URL encode

Tags: asp.net, xss

I am attempting to learn about XSS. I have one ASP page that has an input that POSTs to itself. The variable is URL encoded and displayed back to the user. Is this all that is necessary to defeat XSS?

If not, what would be an example payload that could defeat this?

Comment: I think you want HTML Encode for things you will show in your HTML. You don't want someone to add a <script> tag with their post.

Answer (score 1):

It's enough to use HttpUtility.UrlEncode() to encode output URLs and HttpUtility.HtmlEncode() to encode input from the user or from other sources such as databases.

In the same time, control your input. If your variable has certain type (e.g. user name, numeric, etc) then do not let to enter html tags or "wrong" characters. Validate input type, length, format, and range.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649310.aspx

Comment: link you shared, helped me a lot. Thanks @smirnov